# Residue for quotient of functions

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification, residue-calculus, laurent-series

Let $f, g$ be holomorphic functions on a disk $\mathbb{D}(z_0,r)$ centered at $z_0$ and of radius $r>0$. Suppose $f$ has a simple zero at $z_0$. I want to find an expression for $Res(g/f, z_0)$. But I'm not sure what this expression should look like.

Here's my guess:

Since $f$ has a simple zero at $z_0$, $\exists h(z)$ holomorphic on $\mathbb{D}(z_0,r)$ such that $f(z)=(z-z_0)h(z)$ and $h(z_0)\ne 0$. So that we can represent $g/f = \frac{g(z)}{(z-z_0)h(z)}$, where we observe that $z_0$ is a pole of order 1 of $g/f$. This implies that we can express $$g/f=\frac{a_{-1}}{z-z_0}+\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty a_n(z-z_0)^n$$

Hence, $$a_{-1}=\frac{g(z)}{f(z)}(z-z_0)-\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty a_n(z-z_0)^{n+1}$$

Does this look like a correct approach? I think that this expression is too general because of the infinite series on the right-hand side. Is there a clue I'm missing?

**Update:**

Another approach might be this:

$$g/f = \frac{g(z)}{(z-z_0)h(z)}=\frac{c_0+c_1(z-z_0)+\dots}{d_1(z-z_0)+\dots}=\frac{c_0}{d_1(z-z_0)+\dots}\\
+\frac{c_1(z-z_0)+\dots}{d_1(z-z_0)+\dots}=\frac{a_{-1}}{z-z_0}+\sum a_n(z-z_0)^n$$

But what next?

Comment: $Res(g/f, x_0) = g/f'$. The proof of it is in most textbooks and is very straightforward. Think differentiation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I've finally come up with, with credit to the answer by Zaid Alyafeai.

Since $f$ has a simple zero at $z_0$, we can express it as $f(z)=(z-z_0)h(z)$, where $h(z)$ is holomorphic on $\mathbb{D}(z_0, r)$ and $h(z)\ne 0$ on this set, so that $1/h(z)$ is holomorphic on $\mathbb{D}$ and has Taylor series $1/h(z)=\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty a_k(z-z_0)^k$. Thus $\frac{1}{f}= \frac{1/h(z)}{z-z_0}=\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty a_k(z-z_0)^{k-1}=\frac{a_0}{z-z_0}+O(1)$. $g(z)$ is holomorphic on $\mathbb{D}$, so it has Taylor series $g(z)=\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty b_k (z-z_0)^k=b_0+O[(z-z_0)^2]$. So that $$\frac{g}{f}=\frac{b_0a_0}{z-z_0}+O(1)$$

where $b_0=g(z_0)$. Now, $f'(z)=h'(z)(z-z_0)+h(z)$, and $1/f'(z_0)=1/h(z_0)=a_0$. Hence,

$$Res(\frac{g}{f}, z_0)=\frac{g(z_0)}{f'(z_0)}$$

Answer (score 4):

Suppose that $z_0$ is a simple zero of the fraction

$$\mathrm {Res}(g/f,z_0) = \lim_{z\to z_0}(z-z_0) \frac {g(z)}{f(z)}=\frac {g(z_0)}{f'(z_0)} \tag{1}$$

---

**Alternatively**

Since $f$ has a simple zero at $z_0$

$$\frac{1}{f} = \frac{a_{-1}}{(z-z_0)}+\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k (z-z_0)^k$$

Suppose that $g$ is analytic in a nbhd of $z_0$

$$g(z) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty b_k(z-z_0)^k$$

Then

$$G(z)=\frac{g(z)}{f(z)} = \left( \sum_{k=0}^\infty b_k(z-z_0)^k \right)\left( \frac{a_{-1}}{(z-z_0)}+\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k (z-z_0)^k\right)$$

Finally we have the residue at $z_0$

$$\mathrm {Res}(G(z),z_0) = a_{-1}b_0 \tag{2}$$

Comment: I can't use this definition. I need to expose the constant $c_{-1}$. That is, I can only use the definition that $Res(f, z_0)=c_{-1}$ in the Laurent series.

Comment: @sequence, see my edit. I am not sure if this what you want.

Comment: How do you determine that $a_{-1}b_0$ is the needed constant in the series of $G(z)$? There doesn't appear to be the constant with the index $-1$ there.

Comment: @sequence, to evaluate the residue at $z_0$ you need the coefficient of $(z-z_0)^{-1}$ which is in that case $a_{-1}b_0$.

Comment: Yes, this makes sense. Even though this doesn't the give answer more explicitly, in terms of the functions and their derivatives. We only know that $b_0=g(z_0)$, but we don't know what $a_{-1}$ is.

Comment: @sequence, that seems impossible. You have to have some information about $f(z)$.

Comment: Please see my answer. @ZaidAlyafeai

Comment: @sequence, (+1) glad that hepled you.